# Trying to resize dives after a set have loaded through jquery

Tags: jquery, css

first of all I can't see another way of doing this without Jquery, if there is a better or more proper way of doing this please let me know.

So basically I'm loading three divs in the shapes of circles, inside them each is an inner div with lists generated from a @for loop, so the size will vary (although should never be too big).

Perhaps my css is wrong for a start, but they don't grow as a table border would so I am trying to to find the largest width or height of the largest div and apply that to all of them so they all match.

What I want is a grid of 9 (3x3) cells with a circle in the top left, bottom left and bottom right (but that may change). Below is the sample I have been working with first to try get it right. Note - the lists load data Asynchronously.

```css
.circleBase {
  border-radius: 50%;
  behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}

.type1 {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #ff6600;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.type2 {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #ff6600;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.type3 {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #ff6600;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.InnerCircle1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.InnerCircle2 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.InnerCircle3 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circleBase type1">
  <div class="InnerCircle1">
    <div id="firstTable">
      @Html.Partial("_...").
      <div class="spinner">
      </div>
      <div>Loading...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="circleBase type2">
  <div class="InnerCircle2">
    <div id="secondTable">
      @Html.Partial("_...")
      <div class="spinner">
      </div>
      <div>Loading...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="circleBase type3">
  <div class="InnerCircle3">
    <div id="thirdTable">
      @Html.Partial("_...")
      <div class="spinner">
      </div>
      <div>Loading...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

j query...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Load Age Counts
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Cont/_TableOne",
            type: "GET",
        })
        .done(function (partialViewResult) {
            $("#firstTable").html(partialViewResult)
        })//Set Width/Height
        .done(function () {
            var aw = $(".InnerCircle1").width() + 50;
            var ah = $(".InnerCircle1").height() + 50;
            if (aw > ah) {
                $('.type1').css('width', aw);
                $('.type1').css('height', aw);
            } else {
                $('.type1').css('width', ah);
                $('.type1').css('height', ah);
            };
            console.log("1");
        });

        //Load Age Counts
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Cont/_TableTwo",
            type: "GET",
        })
        .done(function (partialViewResult) {
            $("#secondTable").html(partialViewResult)
        })//Set Width/Height
        .done(function () {
            var aw = $(".InnerCircle2").width() + 50;
            var ah = $(".InnerCircle2").height() + 50;
            if (aw > ah) {
                $('.type2').css('width', aw);
                $('.type2').css('height', aw);
            } else {
                $('.type2').css('width', ah);
                $('.type2').css('height', ah);
            };
            console.log("2");
        });

        //Load Age Counts
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Cont/_TableThree",
            type: "GET",
        })
        .done(function (partialViewResult) {
            $("#thirdTable").html(partialViewResult)
        })//Set Width/Height
        .done(function () {
            var aw = $(".InnerCircle3").width() + 50;
            var ah = $(".InnerCircle3").height() + 50;
            if (aw > ah) {
                $('.type3').css('width', aw);
                $('.type3').css('height', aw);
            } else {
                $('.type3').css('width', ah);
                $('.type3').css('height', ah);
            };
            console.log("3");
        });
    })
    .done(function () {
        //sync up
        var aw = $(".InnerCircle1").width() + 50;
        var ah = $(".InnerCircle1").height() + 50;
        var cw = $(".InnerCircle2").width() + 50;
        var ch = $(".InnerCircle2").height() + 50;
        var dw = $(".InnerCircle3").width() + 50;
        var dh = $(".InnerCircle3").height() + 50;

        var values = [aw, ah, cw, ch, dw, dh];
        var maxVal = 0;

        for (var i = 1; i < values.count(); i++) {
            if (maxVal < values[i]) {
                maxVal = i;
            }
        }
        console.log(maxVal);
    });
</script>
```

I have tried putting each partialview call in its own function and call them with a $.when, but that didn't seem to work either.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.when(TableOne(), TableTwo(), TableThree()).done(function () {
            FinalSync();
        });
    });
</script>
```

it didn't give an error like the other but it didn't sync them all up, also I put a console.log in each one and the final sync logged the call before the others!

Comment: I'm confused, why are you making the same AJAX request 3 times?

Comment: So you want a 3 x 3 grid and have 3 circles in it. The longest inside list in one of the circles determines the height and width of all cells?

Comment: Sorry Rory, It's three different calls, I had deleted that code because I couldn't get it working that way and had to re-create it, just typed it wrong :)

Comment: Hi JP - yes that is pretty much it.  6 of the 9 cells will be blank or contain static info and need no border, 3 of them have lists which I want to have a circular border around them.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/Lnc1yzk3/
You have overcomplicated things!

```
$.when(TableOne(), TableTwo(), TableThree()).done(function () {      
    var maxH = 0;
    $("div.circleBase").each(function() {
        maxH = Math.max(maxH, $(this).height());
    });
    maxH += 50;
    $("div.circleBase").width(maxH);
    $("div.circleBase").height(maxH);
});
```

But since you fire 3 different ajax calls, I'd move the resize to a seperate function like `FinalSync();` and call it after each div is loaded. So FinalSync is not the best name. Maybe SyncWidthAndHeightAfterDivLoaded :)

I assumed you wanted to have each circle the same size.... otherwise just resize the current circle after finishing the ajax request.

Comment: Thanks JP but that doesn't work for me.  the code is running before the tableone(), two... etc is actually done

Comment: On TableOne, Two & three() I have added a console.log() in each and also one in the final statement to set the size of circlebase as you suggested,  that one logs before the ones in TableOne(), Two() and three().

Comment: Perhaps I should have noted also, the reason I resize the divs on each load individually is to stop the table rendering over them.  I do individual resizes so when the data from the for loop renders the div grows with that so it presents properly.  Then when they are all done I want to set them all to be the same as the largest

Comment: It's like the async call to get the data is saying it is done even though the data isn't loaded yet

Comment: ok so wrapping TableOne, two etc... as $.ajax(TableOne()), $.ajax(TableTwo()), now makes the chain work! :)